# LDAP Replication centos 6

Tags: ldap, replication, openldap

I am following reference from http://tech.cbjck.de/2013/03/25/ldap-replication/ for replication. I am running on Centos 6.
Now I am stuck at creating provider.ldif at provider side.

CLI:

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /tmp/provider.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
ldapadd: wrong attributeType at line 5, entry "olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config"
```

Bellow is the provider.ldif code:

```
# new
dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: entryCSN eq
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: entryUUID eq
delete: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by dn="cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com" write by * none
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by dn="cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com" write by dn="cn=synchronisator,dc=my-domain,dc=com" read by * none
#Load the syncprov and accesslog modules.
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: syncprov
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: accesslog
# Accesslog database definitions
dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}bdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap/accesslog
olcSuffix: cn=accesslog
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com
olcBbIndex: default eq
olcDbIndex: entryCSN,objectClass,reqEnd,reqResult,reqStart
olcAccess: to * by dn="cn=synchronisator,dc=my-domain,dc=com" write
# Accesslog db syncprov.
dn: olcOverlay=syncprov,olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changtype: add
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: syncprov
olcSpNoPresent: TRUE
olcSpReloadHint: TRUE
# syncrepl Provider for primary db
dn: olcOverlay=syncprov,olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: syncprov
olcSpNoPresent: TRUE
# accesslog overlay definitions for primary db
dn: olcOverlay=accesslog,olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAccessLogConfig
olcOverlay: accesslog
olcAccessLogDB: cn=accesslogi
olcAccessLogOps: writes
olcAccessLogSuccess: TRUE
olcAccessLogPurge: 02+00:00 00+00:01
```

Besides, I did openLDAP installation by following instruction  http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/vi...POnCentos6.htm

So my database is bdb I think.
This is my olcDatabase={2}bdb configuration:

```
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 6ee7367c
dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcBdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}bdb
olcSuffix: dc=my-domain,dc=com
olcAddContentAcl: FALSE
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcMaxDerefDepth: 15
olcReadOnly: FALSE
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com
olcRootPW: {SSHA}Jit0MhF2L+h7euITiPQLWlGq5g0qPeq+
olcSyncUseSubentry: FALSE
olcMonitoring: TRUE
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcDbCacheSize: 1000
olcDbCheckpoint: 1024 15
olcDbConfig: {0}# $OpenLDAP$
olcDbConfig: {1}# Example DB_CONFIG file for use with slapd(8) BDB/HDB datab
 ases.
olcDbConfig: {2}#
olcDbConfig: {3}# See the Oracle Berkeley DB documentation
olcDbConfig: {4}#   <http://www.oracle.com/technology/documentation/berkeley
 -db/db/ref/env/db_config.html>
olcDbConfig: {5}# for detail description of DB_CONFIG syntax and semantics.
olcDbConfig: {6}#
olcDbConfig: {7}# Hints can also be found in the OpenLDAP Software FAQ
olcDbConfig:: ezh9Iwk8aHR0cDovL3d3dy5vcGVubGRhcC5vcmcvZmFxL2luZGV4LmNnaT9maW
 xlPTI+
olcDbConfig: {9}# in particular:
olcDbConfig: {10}#   <http://www.openldap.org/faq/index.cgi?file=1075>
olcDbConfig: {11}
olcDbConfig: {12}# Note: most DB_CONFIG settings will take effect only upon
 rebuilding
olcDbConfig: {13}# the DB environment.
olcDbConfig: {14}
olcDbConfig: {15}# one 0.25 GB cache
olcDbConfig: {16}set_cachesize 0 268435456 1
olcDbConfig: {17}
olcDbConfig: {18}# Data Directory
olcDbConfig: {19}#set_data_dir db
olcDbConfig: {20}
olcDbConfig: {21}# Transaction Log settings
olcDbConfig: {22}set_lg_regionmax 262144
olcDbConfig: {23}set_lg_bsize 2097152
olcDbConfig: {24}#set_lg_dir logs
olcDbConfig: {25}
olcDbConfig: {26}# Note: special DB_CONFIG flags are no longer needed for "q
 uick"
olcDbConfig:: ezI3fSMgc2xhcGFkZCg4KSBvciBzbGFwaW5kZXgoOCkgYWNjZXNzIChzZWUgdG
 hlaXIgLXEgb3B0aW9uKS4g
olcDbNoSync: FALSE
olcDbDirtyRead: FALSE
olcDbIDLcacheSize: 0
olcDbIndex: objectClass pres,eq
olcDbIndex: cn pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: uid pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: uidNumber pres,eq
olcDbIndex: gidNumber pres,eq
olcDbIndex: mail pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: ou pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: sn pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: givenName pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: loginShell pres,eq
olcDbIndex: memberUid pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: nisMapName pres,eq,sub
olcDbIndex: nisMapEntry pres,eq,sub
olcDbLinearIndex: FALSE
olcDbMode: 0600
olcDbSearchStack: 16
olcDbShmKey: 0
olcDbCacheFree: 1
olcDbDNcacheSize: 0
structuralObjectClass: olcBdbConfig
entryUUID: 5ec21964-8a8d-1035-8e79-750eecdc11b0
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20160330063542Z
entryCSN: 20160330063542.541411Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20160330063542Z
```

Could anyone help me find out how to solve this error? I would be grateful for your kindly help?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all the {0}s, {1}s {2}s, etc. OpenLDAP will put them in itself as necessary,